# Name for a one-dimensional domain/set that is topologically like a circle?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is there a special name for a continuous one-dimensional domain/set that wraps around on itself?

Example 1: The set of unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Example 2: The set of points on a square.

Example 3: $[0,2\pi)$ with an additional link between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: What's wrong with "a circle"?

Comment: @Arthur It might not be a circle. It might be an ellipse. It is only *topologically* like a circle.

Comment: "Connected, compact 1 dimensional manifold" describes what you want.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Which of those adjectives disqualifies something like $[0,1)$?

Comment: Why not "a topological circle"?

Comment: @Museful "Compact" disqualifies $[0,1)$. And if "a circle" is too restrictive, then I second "a topological circle". However, if the current context is topology and not geometry, then I believe that you don't have to qualify it. "Simple, closed curve" is also a commonly used possibility.

Comment: @Museful Also, $[0,1)$ is not a manifold* because it is not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, namely at $0$. *Technically, this is the definition of a "manifold without boundary," but some people use "manifold" to mean this.

Comment: Normally you would say your set is homeomorphic/diffeomorphic/some-other-morphic to a circle depending what property you want to emphasize.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Would it be correct to say that $[0,1]$ is a connected, compact 1 dimensional space?

Comment: You could say $[0,1]$ is a connected, compact 1 dimensional _manifold with boundary_. The other comments do a better job answering your question, topological circle is the best terminology.

Comment: A set $S$ homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: It needs to be one-holed in some sense (if you don't want to allow multiwraps).